# An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows

Tags: ajax

I'm getting this AJAX error when I try Add content in Panel and see AJAX errors
 I have test at localhost the not errors but when I uploaded to hosting is have this problems.

I don't know why

My modules using:
Panels Bootstrap Layouts 7.x-3.0+12-dev, Panels 7.x-3.5, Nodejs integration 7.x-1.9, Chat Room 7.x-2, Views Bootstrap 7.x-3.1
Bootstrap version   jQuery 1.7.2, jQuery Update jQuery 1.7.2 (configure) and jQuery UI 1.10.2

- Im check my status is
  HTTP request status Fails
  Your system or network configuration does not allow Drupal to access web pages, resulting in reduced functionality. This could be due to your webserver configuration or PHP settings, and should be resolved in order to download information about available updates, fetch aggregator feeds, sign in via OpenID, or use other network-dependent services. If you are certain that Drupal can access web pages but you are still seeing this message, you may add $conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE; to the bottom of your settings.php file.

Thanks for any helps

[image]